# Bundle argument of type string gives Null but is not Null

Tags: android, kotlin

I pass an Bundle argument to a Fragment of the type String. Than I'm trying to get the String but get a Null as it returns.

Activity

```
 locationFragment = LocationFragment()

    bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("id ", intent.getStringExtra("id"))

    locationFragment.arguments = bundle

    // Get the support fragment manager instance
    val manager = supportFragmentManager

    // Begin the fragment transition using support fragment manager
    val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()

    // Replace the fragment on container
    transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment,locationFragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)

    // Finishing the transition
    transaction.commit()
```

Fragment

```
val bdl = arguments
println("Id: " + bdl?.getString("id"))
```

Expecting

> I/System.out: Id :1948

Result

> I/System.out: Id: null

[Android debug screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/697h3.png)

Comment: Please post full code of setting up a bundle while making transaction.

Comment: add some more code

Comment: YOu added the key "id " with space but tried to read "id" without space

Comment: Because while you put key _"id "_ there is some space after _id_. While you retrieving there is not.

Comment: yeah the space is the problem
use some static strings from another class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in the code I deduct that the fault lies in the ID being inconsistent. 
What you do is you put `"id "` with a space, but when you try to get the value back, you use `"id"` (without a space).

In Kotlin one of the approaches would be to create a companion object which would hold your IDs and make sure you'll always use the right one.

```
companion object {
    const val BUNDLE_ID = "bundle_id"
}

bundle.putString(BUNDLE_ID, intent.getStringExtra(BUNDLE_ID))
bundle?.getString(BUNDLE_ID)
```